# Não é possível converter string em float

Tags: python-3.x, sklearn

Estou tentando rodar um modelo de classificação e estou tendo o retorno de que não é possível converter string em float nas variaveis preditoras. Quando dou um dtypes vejo que todas as variáveis são float ou Int. Eu fiz todo o processo de analise exploratoria, pré processamento: todas as variáveis são numericas, fiz escala, fiz seleção de variaveis com regressão logistica e eliminação recursiva. Segue código:

```
from sklearn import tree
x_treino = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
y_treino = ['tt']
x_teste = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'] 

# Criando o objeto logistic regression
model = LogisticRegression()

# Criando o objeto tree para classificação
model = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()

# Treinando o modelo com dados de treino e checando o score
model.fit(x_treino, y_treino)
model.score(x_treino, y_treino)

# Previsões
valores_previstos = model.predict(x_teste)
```

Podem me ajudar como resolver isto. Tem alguma forma de olhar linha a linha nestas variaveis afim de verificar se há algum caractere nelas??Obrigado

Comment: Olá Pessoal. Eu não consegui resolver este problema, então optei fazer por outro caminho usando o pacote train_test_split do sklearn. Criei manualmente a divisão de dados de teste e treino. Feito isso rodei os modelos de Machine Learning sem problemas.

Comment: Boa tarde, Edi. Acredito que você quis dizer "model.score(x_teste, y_teste)" ao invés de "model.score(x_treino, y_treino)" no seu código, correto?

Answer (score 1):

Pra verificar se elas estao vazias ou não, voce pode fazer um validação com if.

```
for v in x_treino: # "Para cada valor em x_treino"
    if v == None:  # Se o valor for None (nada)
        print('Valor vazio no x_treino')
        break
    else:
        model = LogisticRegression()
```

Da mesma forma, voce pude usar o != para fazer a validação.
Espero ter ajudado.